# Python ctypes calling simple c++ dll

Tags: c++, python-2.7, ctypes

I am really having a hard time to call a simple c++ dll from python using ctypes

Below is my C++ code :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
  __declspec(dllexport) char const* greet()
{
  return "hello, world";
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

...

My Python code :

```
import ctypes
testlib = ctypes.CDLL("CpLib.dll");
print testlib.greet();
```

When i run my py script, I get this strange  return value of  `-97902232`

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell ctypes what type the return value is, and so it assumes that it is an integer. But it is in fact a pointer. Set the restype attribute to let ctypes know how to interpret the return value.

```
import ctypes 
testlib = ctypes.CDLL("CpLib.dll")
testlib.greet.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
print testlib.greet()
```